# Jssor Slider Navigator Transition

Tags: slider, slideshow, transition

how to do jssor slider direction navigator with transition effects. it just slides images without any effect.

I set the transitions, but it does not work with the direction navigator.

Answer (score 0):

For dragging (I suppose will also work for arrows navigation) you should use this option

$SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint

Instead of $EaseOutQuint you can use one of these (list below) - jssor documentation lacks on this, so I had to extract manually from .js ... enjoy trying different effects :D

$EaseLinear
$EaseGoBack
$EaseSwing
$EaseInQuad
$EaseOutQuad
$EaseInOutQuad
$EaseInCubic
$EaseOutCubic
$EaseInOutCubic
$EaseInQuart
$EaseOutQuart
$EaseInOutQuart
$EaseInQuint
$EaseOutQuint
$EaseInOutQuint
$EaseInSine
$EaseOutSine
$EaseInOutSine
$EaseInExpo
$EaseOutExpo
$EaseInOutExpo
$EaseInCirc
$EaseOutCirc
$EaseInOutCirc
$EaseInElastic
$EaseOutElastic
$EaseInOutElastic
$EaseInBack
$EaseOutBack
$EaseInOutBack
$EaseInBounce
$EaseOutBounce
$EaseOutBounce
$EaseInOutBounce
$EaseInBounce
$EaseOutBounce
$EaseInWave
$EaseOutWave
$EaseOutJump
$EaseInJump

P.S. Dragging works, let me know if also arrow navigation is ok

Comment: i wanted effects like in _SlideshowTransitions, but thanks its also useful and works on arrow navigation too